# Samba prompts for a password twice

Tags: samba, authentication

I have a relatively new samba install configured to give Windows users access to some log files on a syslog server ("littleEngineer"). However it's prompting for a password to just get a share listing by accessing `\\littleEngineer\`, is there a way to disable this behavior so that it will only prompt for a password if the user tries to access a secured share?

This is my `testparm` output:

```
root@littleEngineer /var/log/samba $ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "idmap uid" option is deprecated
WARNING: The "idmap gid" option is deprecated
Processing section "[aviationLogs]"
WARNING: The security=share option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
        workgroup = BIZCO
        realm = BIZCO.COM
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        security = SHARE
        password server = BIZCO.COM
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        utmp = Yes
        template shell = /bin/bash
        winbind use default domain = Yes
        idmap config * : range = 16777216-33554431
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        cups options = raw

[aviationLogs]
        comment = Apache httpd Log Files (Access and Error)
        path = /var/log/central-logs/aviation
        force user = root
        guest ok = Yes
```

**EDIT:**

Client: Windows 7 SP1
Client machine is VPN'd into the customer's local network but is not part of their AD domain. Samba is configured for Bizco.com (our client), let's say my laptop is part of the Fuzzypants.com domain.

From `log.%m` when I pull the share up and click cancel on the prompt:

```
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.812088,  3] lib/access.c:338(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from xxx.xxx.28.194 (xxx.xxx.28.194)
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.812201,  3] smbd/oplock.c:922(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.812372,  3] smbd/oplock_linux.c:226(linux_init_kernel_oplocks)
  Linux kernel oplocks enabled
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.812519,  3] smbd/process.c:1662(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 159 (0 toread)
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.812569,  3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)
  switch message SMBnegprot (pid 2467) conn 0x0
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813049,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813104,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LANMAN1.0]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813143,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [Windows for Workgroups 3.1a]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813177,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LM1.2X002]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813212,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LANMAN2.1]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813247,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [NT LM 0.12]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813315,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.002]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813350,  3] smbd/negprot.c:598(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.???]
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813514,  3] smbd/negprot.c:401(reply_nt1)
  not using SPNEGO
[2014/08/13 21:56:28.813553,  3] smbd/negprot.c:704(reply_negprot)
  Selected protocol NT LM 0.12
[2014/08/13 21:56:46.975628,  1] smbd/process.c:457(receive_smb_talloc)
  receive_smb_raw_talloc failed for client xxx.xxx.28.194 read error = NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET.
[2014/08/13 21:56:46.975865,  3] smbd/server_exit.c:181(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (failed to receive smb request)
```

I can give the log output from a successful authentication but it's probably not as informative.

**EDIT #2**

Since the last log didn't have anything telling I went through with the login prompt and began to see `check_ntlm_password` in `log.%m`:

```
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988239,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user []\[]@[] with the new password interface
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988274,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: []\[]@[]
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988328,  3] auth/auth.c:268(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password: guest authentication for user [] succeeded
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988379,  3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)
  switch message SMBtconX (pid 6290) conn 0x0
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988450,  3] lib/access.c:338(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from XXX.XXX.29.76 (XXX.XXX.29.76)
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988613,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [bizco]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76] with the new password interface
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988651,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [XXXXXXVLP01]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76]
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988735,  3] auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'davisja5' in passdb.
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988772,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [davisja5] -> [davisja5] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988819,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [BIZCO]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76] with the new password interface
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988853,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [XXXXXXVLP01]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76]
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988927,  3] auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'davisja5' in passdb.
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.988964,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [davisja5] -> [davisja5] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989005,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [BIZCO]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76] with the new password interface
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989039,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [XXXXXXVLP01]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76]
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989092,  3] auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'davisja5' in passdb.
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989126,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [davisja5] -> [davisja5] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989167,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [BIZCO]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76] with the new password interface
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989201,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [XXXXXXVLP01]\[davisja5]@[XXX.XXX.29.76]
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989253,  3] auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'davisja5' in passdb.
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989286,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [davisja5] -> [davisja5] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989359,  3] smbd/password.c:721(authorise_login)
  authorise_login: ACCEPTED: guest account and guest ok (root)
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989566,  3] passdb/lookup_sid.c:1754(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for root
[2014/08/14 12:33:59.989752,  3] smbd/service.c:872(make_connection_snum)
  Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
```

Comment: Try setting `log level = 2` then check the logs. Also what Windows version are you using?

Comment: I've taken it up to `log level = 4` but nothing else shows up either in `log.smbd` or the machine-specific log file (except startup messages).

Comment: Look for the user used by Windows for listing the shares.

Comment: @JoelDavis - take a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/635782/windows-is-asking-for-password-to-browse-the-available-file-shares-on-samba

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Updated my question with the log excerpt of my attempt to connect and clicking cancel.

Comment: @slm unfortunately that answer suggests that I use share-level security which I'm already using up above (you can see it in the `testparm` output)

Comment: I don't see any `check_ntlm_password` in that log. I'm also not sure how `security = SHARE` (which is deprecated) gets along with `password server` option.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu that's probably due to me clicking cancel. I was hoping that whatever was causing the problem would be in the logs without doing the actual login (which produces more output).

Comment: I also commented out `password server` to the same effect. If it matters at all, I get prompted for credentials when listing all shares as well as when I click into a particular share (even one with `guest ok` and `guest only`).

Comment: Actually you should have tried the opposite. Set `security` to `ads` or `domain` and let the `password server` as it is (uncommented).

Comment: Already tried ADS for `security` yesterday with the same effect.

Comment: Tried `domain` and it prompts for a password but gives me a permissions error thereafter.

Comment: Instead of removing completely usernames and domains, could you replace me with something a bit more meaningful? Perhaps something like `user1` or `local-username`, `domain1` and so on to see if they appear multiple times.

Comment: Any instance of "BIZCO" that show up are for the customer's domain, my company's domain doesn't appear in the output. My username in the above output is `davisja5` and looks to be the only one up there as well.

Comment: fwiw, the issue turned out to be due to using a client that was on a different AD domain. Once I switched to a computer on the domain, authentication only appeared once.