# Correct syntax for mounting smbfs in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, samba, samba4

I have two networked FreeBSD 11.1 servers, both installed with Samba 4.6.x. No issues with Samba, which browses nicely from any Windows client, but I cannot seem to find the syntax to mount samba using CLI from one to the other of the servers (or indeed from one on itself).

Both servers use the same remoteuser + password to access Samba shares. The servers are standalone and use their own users/groups for authentication/permissions;   there's no AD.

Works:

```
smbclient \\\\servername\\myfiles -U servername\\remoteuser
smbclient '\\servername\myfiles' -U servername\\remoteuser
  (they're equivalent)
```

Doesn't work (taken from *history*):

```
mount_smbfs -I serverIP //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -I servername //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
smbutil -v login //remoteuser@servername/myfiles    
mount_smbfs -I smbclient \\\\servername\\myfiles -U servername\\remoteuser    
mount_smbfs -U servername\\remoteuser \\\\servername\\Usr_files ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -U servername\\remoteuser //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //\\servername\\remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //\\\\servername\\remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //servername/remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -I serverIP //servername/remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //remoteuser@servername.FQDN/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs //remoteuser:remotepassword@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs \\\\remoteuser@servername\\myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount -t smbfs //remoteuser@serverIP/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -I servername //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -I servername -U \\\\servername\\remoteuser //remoteuser@servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint    
mount_smbfs -I servername -U \\\\servername\\remoteuser //servername/myfiles ~/mountpoint
```

You get the idea :) I've tried troubleshooting what it's expecting vs. what I'm giving, in the remote server's smbd log, but I still can't seem to find the command needed.

The error message is "permission denied", or in the remote log, a mix of NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER ("your syntax for the user/system name was wrong"), NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND ("your syntax for the share or something else was wrong")and NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ("your syntax for credentials was wrong"). As the first command above *doee* work, it's clear the issue is one of using incorrect syntax/args, and not an actual permissions, mission resource, or config issue.

What am I fundamentally misunderstanding about Samba's CLI syntax, here, and what is the correct command?

Comment: [Your question needs to contain a description of what actually happened, not just "doesn't work".](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)

Comment: I'll add it but there's not much point. The error just translates as "your syntax/args aren't given correctly", which is clear anyway.

Comment: If you knew what the answer was, you wouldn't be here asking the question.  Stop assuming, and [give people reading your question the actual errors and log entries, and indeed the actual commands that you are issuing without bowdlerization](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).  Compare your quite poorly written question to ones like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250435/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150125/ where the questioners do that.

Answer (score 1):

mount_smbfs doesn't work properly with smbv2 and beyond.
The only solution I found is to change some settings on the samba server in global section of smb.conf

```
    client ntlmv2 auth = no
    ntlm auth = yes
```

setting the above let me mount my samba share on FreeBSD host with mount_smbfs command and write to the share

```
mount_smbfs -I 10.0.4.8 -U someuser //someuser@samba4/someshare /sambad01
```

and test_parm on the samba server shows the following:

```
root@samba:/ # testparm
Load smb config files from /usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        client NTLMv2 auth = No
        log file = /var/log/samba4/%m
        map to guest = Bad User
        netbios name = SAMBA4
        ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

smbstatus (NT1 for mount_smbfs and smb3_11 for my windows host):

```
root@samba:/ # smbstatus

Samba version 4.10.11
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1200    someuser   someuser   d04 (ipv4:10.0.4.4:43318)                 NT1               -                    -
13014   someuser   someuser   10.10.10.14 (ipv4:10.10.10.14:61017)      SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)
```

Answer (score -2):

... works

```
mount_smbfs -I 10.10.10.10 -U someuser -W someworkgroup //someuser@10.10.10.10/somesharename /mnt/somemountname
```

Comment: I do not get it

Comment: Is it the addition of the -W that made the difference? Some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: When I had this issue, the -W helped me because it needed to know the domain/workgroup of the server you are joining.  Once I added a domain, the client knew which server it should be connecting to